# How do you order random values into numerical order in python?

Tags: python, random

```
import random
import time
print ' Welcome to the lottery number generator'

num_1 = random.randrange(53)+1 #Random numbers
num_2 = random.randrange(53)+1 #Random numbers
num_3 = random.randrange(53)+1 #Random numbers
num_4 = random.randrange(53)+1 #Random numbers
num_5 = random.randrange(53)+1 #Random numbers

Bonus = random.randrange(42)+1 #Bonus ball random numbers

print 'Here are the numbers that have been drawn'
time.sleep(1)
print 'Your first ball'
time.sleep(1)
print num_1
time.sleep(1)
print 'Your second ball'
time.sleep(1)
print num_2
time.sleep(1)
print 'Your third ball'
time.sleep(1)
print num_3
time.sleep(1)
print 'Your fourth ball'
time.sleep(1)
print num_4
time.sleep(1)
print 'Your fifth ball'
time.sleep(1)
print num_5
time.sleep(1)
print 'The bonus ball'
time.sleep(1)
print Bonus
```

Please can someone tell me how to put the random numbers into numerical order????
The code works i just need to put them into numerical order.
There will be 5 ball that will need to be put into numerical order and the bonus ball needs to be shown by itself.

Comment: Create a `list` from the generated numbers use `sorted`.

Comment: If you start to add numbers to your variable names it's most likely that you should use a list instead.

Comment: With this code you might get duplicate ball numbers - do you mind that?

Comment: No could you sort it???????

Comment: @gbws: I Don't understand your question (even with 7 question marks). Put the data in a list and sort the list. That's the way how it's done.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using variables put the random numbers in a list and then sort it using either `sorted` or `list.sort`:

```
>>> import random
```

Use a [`list comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a list containing random items:

```
>>> nums = [random.randrange(53)+1 for _ in xrange(5)]
>>> nums
[51, 49, 23, 27, 29]
```

`sorted`:

```
>>> sorted(nums)     #return a new sorted list, original list is not affected
[23, 27, 29, 49, 51]
```

`list.sort`:

```
>>> nums.sort()      #sort the list in-place
>>> nums
[23, 27, 29, 49, 51]
```

**Code:**

```
pos = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth']
for ball, ind in zip(sorted(nums), pos):
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'Your {} ball'.format(ind)
    time.sleep(1)
    print ball
```

Comment: Yeah, and put your items in a list (and probably learn about lists first ;-)

Comment: To eliminate duplicates you could use `nums = random.sample(range(1, 54), 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make a list of numbers, rather than making several different variables. Then you can just use `list.sort()` to sort the numbers.

```
numlist = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    numlist.append(random.randrange(53)+1)
numlist.append(random.randrange(42)+1)

numlist.sort()
```